# Why do browsers insert 2 linebreaks into an empty body element?

Tags: javascript, html

Occasionally whitespace inside HTML matters seriously. Therefore I wanted to know why Chrome as well as Firefox insert 2 linebreaks in an empty body element.

loading a page with

```
<body></body>
```

or equally

```
<body />
```

gives a body with 2 linebreaks in it:

```
document.body.outerHTML // <body>↵↵</body>
document.body.firstChild // #text, 2 linefeeds
```

setting innerHTML or outerHTML to "" or deleting the textnode child give a really empty body

```
document.body.outerHTML // "<body></body>"
```

Why do browser do this magical insertion of the 2 linefeeds?

Comment: *"...or equally `<body />`..."* Just FYI, that's just an opening body tag with no closing body tag in HTML. (It's a closed tag in XHTML, but you're probably not using XHTML.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing line breaks from elsewhere in your HTML (before the `head`, between `head` and `body`). If you remove **all** linebreaks leading up to `<body>` and after `</body>`, you won't have any in the body.

The reason is probably largely historical related to tolerating invalid markup, but it's codified now: The full details are in the spec [starting here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#parsing-main-inhtml). Notice, for instance, that both the ["in head" insertion mode](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#parsing-main-inhead) and the ["after head" insertion mode](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-after-head-insertion-mode) process whitespace by [inserting the character](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#insert-a-character).

Comment: let my try, that fits together with my observation that a script tag after the body shows up inside the body, in at least in chrome.

Comment: @citykid - *"...a script tag after the body..."* If you mean a `script` tag after `</body>` and before `</html>`, that's invalid (but browsers will tolerate it by moving it to the `body`). The [`html` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-html-element) cannot have `script` as a direct child.